# Visual Studio 2010 Project File - UserProperties Element

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, svn

Earlier today I grabbed a copy of a project from our SVN repo.

I did not make any changes, except to add a missing dependency. For some reason, this modified the project file (in this case .vbproj).

When I diff the 2, the only difference is in the UserProperties element. The attributes and values are not changed, but the ORDER they are presented in the file is switched.

BASE:

```
     <UserProperties BuildVersion_UseGlobalSettings="True" BuildVersion_AssemblyInfoFilename="" />
```

WORKING COPY:

```
     <UserProperties BuildVersion_AssemblyInfoFilename="" BuildVersion_UseGlobalSettings="True" />
```

Does anyone know why this occurs? I don't want to gum up the proj file for others on check in.